# Highlight exact string with jquery using contains selector

Tags: jquery, string, match

I'm trying to highlight all fields that contain a certain string exactly, in the example below I will also match someuser2, someuser3 etc.

```
$("div.forumbody .username:contains('someuser')").css("background", "#6a5acd");
```

How can I search for the exact string and make the background of the field #6a5acd?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/jquery-custom-selector-for-selecting-elements-by-exact-text-textequals/)

Create custom selector

```
$.expr[':'].textEquals = function(a, i, m) {
return $(a).text().match("^" + m[3] + "$");
};
```

and use it

```
$("div.forumbody .username:textEquals('someuser')").css("background", "#6a5acd");
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks right to me... Make sure your selectors are working right without the contain...

```
$("div.forumbody .username").css("background", "#6a5acd");
```

**EDIT**

For text fields:

```
$("div.forumbody .username[value*=someuser]").css("background", "#6a5acd");
```

Or if they are not prepopulated (building off Govind's answer) :

```
$.expr[':'].valHas = function(a, i, m) {
  return $(a).val().match("^" + m[3] + "$");
};

$("div.forumbody .username:valHas('someuser')")
```

**DOUBLE EDIT**

This tested working and simpler:

```
jQuery("div.forumbody .username:text[value*='someuser']").css("background", "#6a5acd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add a extend pseudo function:

```
$.expr[':'].textEquals = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().match("^" + arg + "$");
    };
});
```

Then you can do:

```
$("div.forumbody .username:textEquals('someuser')").css("background", "#6a5acd");
```